# Detecting open button in an upload dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

Is there a way to detect if the open button in an upload dialog is clicked using javascript or query?[image: this button]

**UPDATE :** 
I will show you my sample code:

```
<input type = "file" name = "imgUpload" id = "trngImgUpload" style = "display : none;" multiple>
<button class="btnTools" onclick = "trngOpenVidUploadDialog()" ><img src ="@Url.Content("~/Images/video_icon.jpg")" class ="img3"/></button>
<script>
function trngOpenVidUploadDialog() {
        //$('#modalMatchingTypePairType').modal('hide');
        //console.log(123);
        $('#trngImgUpload').trigger("click");

    };
    $('input[type=file]').change(function () {
        if (this.files) {
            alert('changed');
            var path = sendVidFile($('#trngImgUpload')[0].files[0], 1);
            $('#page' + currId).append('<div class = "vidDR" id = "tTool' + (toolIdCounter) + '"><div class = "del"></div><embed autostart="false" class = "vid" src="' + path + '"></embed></div>');
            $('.vidDR').resizable({
                containment: '#page' + currId
            }).draggable({
                containment: '#page' + currId
            });
            $(".vidDR").click(function () {
                alert(1);
            });
            $('#trngImgUpload').val("");
            $('#tTool' + toolIdCounter).contextmenu(function () {
                $(this).remove();
            });
            toolIdCounter++;
        }
    });
</script>
```

I already tried using change event but nothing happens. I don't know whats wrong in my code.

Comment: may be you can change onchange event of filecontrol

Answer (score 1):

No! That is not possible.

But if you want to have an eye on your input `type=file` then you might like to use `change()` event on the input.

Check the snippet:

```js
$('input[type=file]').change(function() {
  if (this.files) {
    $('pre').html('Files selected. (open clicked.)');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="imgUpload" id="trngImgUpload" style="display : none;" multiple>
<button class="btnTools" onclick="trngOpenVidUploadDialog()">
  <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ilb/Perspective%20Button%20-%20Windows.png" class="img3" />
</button>
<script>
  function trngOpenVidUploadDialog() {
    //$('#modalMatchingTypePairType').modal('hide');
    //console.log(123);
    $('#trngImgUpload').trigger("click");

  };
  $('input[type=file]').change(function() {
    if (this.files) {
      alert('changed');
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I've tried your answer but nothing happens. I have updated my question. kindly see it

Comment: @JanLeeYu seems working, what do you mean by _nothing happens_?

Comment: The code I have above, when I run it and clicked on `.btnTools` it opens the upload dialog. But after that, when I choose a file and clicked open, it closes the dialog and nothing happens. The alert is not even executing. I don't know whats wrong

Comment: check the browser's console. Do you see any error there?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot capture the action on the 'Open' button, however you can capture the action upon **changes on the file input**. E.g. when the user has **selected a new file using the file input**.

Example as follows:

```js
// input on change event listener
$('#file-upload').on('change', function() {
  alert('File Attached: ' + $('#file-upload').val());
});
```

```html
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- file upload input -->
<input type="file" id="file-upload">
```

Hope this helps.